# Manually submit form in Netsuite restlet

Tags: netsuite

I created a restlet and am trying to submit form data to an online customer form.  How do I submit an online customer form from the restlet?

I created the form in Setup -> Marketing -> Online Customer Forms.

Restlet ('submit' is the POST method):

```
function submit(formData){
  //How do manually submit formData to a Online Customer Form?
  //formData is a JSON object like:
  // { "firstname": "John"}...
}
```

The form is using a url like this one:

https://forms.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl?compid=5555555&formid=33&h=4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to use restlet when submitting from Online Customer Form?

Comment: I'm new to netsuite.  I'm basically just trying to create a lead from an external form.  Is there a better way?

Comment: you do not need a restlet. Online Customer Form alone can get information from your lead. The external URL can be embedded on your website by using an iFrame.